# How to insert \pgfplotmark in a sentence?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, bullets

Using picture in a box displays `\pgfuseplotmark` at the beginning of the page and above the text, that's not where I want the mark to be displayed. Using picture directly in a sentence doesn't display the mark. How to display \pgfuseplotmark between the words "hello world"?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newbox\aMark
\setbox\aMark\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}\path node{\pgfuseplotmark{*}};\end{tikzpicture}}

% WRONG DISPLAY
hello\copy\aMark wrold

% NO DISPLAY
% hello\begin{tikzpicture}\path node{\pgfuseplotmark{*}};\end{tikzpicture}world

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not require Ti*k*Z, "only" pgf. Going along your `\newbox` route, you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{plothandlers,plotmarks}
\begin{document}

\newbox\aMark
\setbox\aMark\hbox{\begin{pgfpicture}\pgfuseplotmark{*}\end{pgfpicture}}

hello \copy\aMark\ world

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. These days there are some real efforts under way to make it more transparent what is needed for what, so please stay tuned and patient.

As for your comment: I do not *think* this is related to `\pgfuseplotmark{*}`, at least the way I would use it immediately worked:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepgflibrary{plothandlers,plotmarks}
\begin{document}
\newbox\aMark 
\setbox\aMark\hbox{\begin{pgfpicture}\pgfuseplotmark{*}\end{pgfpicture}} 
\newbox\bMark 
\setbox\bMark\hbox{\begin{pgfpicture}\pgfuseplotmark{o}\end{pgfpicture}} 

\noindent\copy\aMark\ one

\noindent\copy\bMark\ two

\end{document}
```

[image]